# Unable to integrate Tomcat with Apache HTTP Server

Tags: tomcat, mod-jk

I have followed several tutorials on how to integrate Appache HTTP Server with Tomcat but the tomcat servers just do not load. I am doing this on a Ubuntu 20.04.1

I can load up the site http://myurl.com:8080/examples. However, when I call https://myurl.com/examples/ I get Not Found error stating:

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.41(Ubuntu) Server at myurl.com port 443

I thought https://myurl.com/examples should work.

My set up in /opt/tomcat/conf includes server.xml and a line for AJP 1.3 connector as follows

`<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" port="8009" secretRequired="false" redirectPort="8443" enableLookups="false" />`

My /opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml includes an entry admin-gui

The firewall allows Apache and port 8080 (among others)

My /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service is as follows

```
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -      Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My /etc/apache2/workers.properties is as follows

```
# Define 1 real worker using ajp13
worker.list=worker1

#set properties for worker1 (ajp13)
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
# configure jk-status
worker.list=jk-status
worker.jk-status.type=status
worker.jk-status.read_only=true
# configure jk-manager
worker.list=jk-manager
worker.jk-manager.type=status
```

it is referenced from /etc/apache2/mods-available/jk.conf as
`JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties`

At /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf I have
`<VirtualHost *:80>`
`DocumentRoot /var/www/html`
`JKMount /* worker1`
`</VirtualHost>`

Tomcat status is running (Active)

What am I missing?

Comment: `JkMount /` forwards only the exact URI path `/`. Probably you want `JkMount /*`.

Comment: I am sorry it did not show clearly on my post. it is JkMount /*  it does not work still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only provided the JKMount for the http virtual host. You need to add `JkMountCopy On` in the https virtual host (or equivalent).

JKMounts are not copied between virtual hosts by default.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I have added JkMountCopy on <VirtualHost *:443> and that did it